# 301 redirect for html files in one directory only to Custom Post Type in Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am struggling to get my head around an htaccess rule to redirect requests for an html file to go to a custom post. I have looked on here and in other places and nearly got there.

I want to redirect **ONLY** mydomain.com/profiles/*.html to mydomain.com/name_profile/*

So mydomain.com/profiles/smith.html to mydomain.com/name_profiles/smith. There are some 900 html files to be redirected and they are all contained in this directory. Other html files in the domain I need to leave correctly associated.

I currently have

```
RedirectMatch 301  ^/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1/$2/
RedirectMatch 301  ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1/$2/$3/
```

But this redirects all html pages not just the ones in the profiles directory.

I am new at htaccess and have found several tutorials but none at a level I can understand, so any help is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Place this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteRule ^profiles/([^.]+)\.html$ /name_profiles/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks I have tried this it works but it now messes up my members/index.html link and strips the .html from that. The only thin unusual with the members folder is that it is htpasswd protected. Any other thoughts?

Comment: No it doesn't.

mydomain.com/profiles/smith.html etc (no index.html only various names.html.
mydomain.com/members/index.html

Comment: In that case above rule **cannot impact** your `mydomain.com/members/index.html` since regex used is `^profiles/` which means it will only impact URIs that start with `/profiles/`. I think you have other rules and/or other .htaccess in your system causing this.

Comment: OK I will do some more digging. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profiles/([^.]+)\.html/? name_profiles/$1 [DPI,L,R]
```

Or better, remove your RewriteMatch rules and replace with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html/? $1/$2 [DPI,L,R]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html/? $1/$2/$3 [DPI,L,R]
```

This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for htaccess files. 
If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();`
By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for htaccess files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf`
and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`

Comment: Thanks I have tried this it works but it now messes up my members/index.html link and strips the .html from that. The only thin unusual with the members folder is that it is htpasswd protected. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Whatever happens to members has nothing to do with the rule I gave you. It must be related to your `RedirectMatch` rules. It would be better to replace everything with RewriteRules. Try the updated answer. :)